# Kendo Grid - disable popup edit auto close (achieved), but unable to close the popup when click "Cancel"

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So basically I achieved what I want that is to disable Kendo Grid Popup Edit auto closing after submit based on this:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-prevent-popup-close-on-edit

But, after submitting, when I click "Cancel" button, it won't allow me to close the popup edit. I'm not sure what cause it. Before submit anything, I can close the popup edit as usual when click "Cancel" button.

Here is little modification I made to the above code:

https://dojo.telerik.com/oYoxEdEj

I just change the text of the "Cancel" button to "Finished".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call window.close on 'Finished' button click.

```
$(".k-grid-cancel").on('click', function(e) {
    editWindow.close();
});
```

Edited example: [Close event](https://dojo.telerik.com/uXUPijah)